# Swift - Block loop from continuing until download operation finishes

Tags: swift, asynchronous, foreach, alamofire

I am currently trying to download multiple files upon user request for a game. My goal is to have it download only one file at a time and stop executing code until that file has finished downloading.

My code is an array of JSON objects, in each contains a path for where to download them to(path) and the URL of the file. I am looping through the array and using AlamoFire to download them with a `.downloadProgress` closure.

```
Alamofire.download(
json["url"].stringValue,
method: .get,
to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (Alamoprogress) in
info.stringValue = "Downloading: " + filename
progress.doubleValue = Alamoprogress.fractionCompleted * 100
}).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
})
```

To try to make sure it only downloaded a single file at a time, I set up a DispatchQueue and moved the Alamofire request inside of synchronous operation:

```
for jsonObject in jsonArray{
    queue.async {
    print("Started downloading " + filename)
    info.stringValue = "Downloading: " + filename
    info.placeholderString = "Downloading: " + filename
    info.isEnabled = true
    info.isHidden = false
    progress.isHidden = false
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = filepath
        return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
    }
    Alamofire.download(
        json["url"].stringValue,
        method: .get,
        to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (Alamoprogress) in
                info.stringValue = "Downloading: " + filename
            progress.doubleValue = Alamoprogress.fractionCompleted * 100
        }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                            })
           }
}
```

However, the debug log will continue to loop while downloading files and will download them **a**synchronously. This causes the `info` box and `progress` bar to go nuts while downloading, as it's downloading them all at once. I believe I have set up a synchronous loop however it may still be asynchronous in that is it looping through.

How can I prevent asynchronous downloads here?

Comment: There is no loop in the code you posted.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated it to include the loop, what I had before was just what was in the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a semaphore so only one is downloading at a time:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

for jsonObject in jsonArray {
    queue.async {
        semaphore.wait()

        print("Started downloading " + filename)
        info.stringValue = "Downloading: " + filename
        info.placeholderString = "Downloading: " + filename
        info.isEnabled = true
        info.isHidden = false
        progress.isHidden = false
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL = filepath
            return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
        }
        Alamofire.download( json["url"].stringValue, method: .get, to: destination)
            .downloadProgress{ Alamoprogress in
                info.stringValue = "Downloading: " + filename
                progress.doubleValue = Alamoprogress.fractionCompleted * 100
            }
            .response { response in
                semaphore.signal()
            }
    }
}
```