# Swift Async Requests Loop Duplicating

Tags: swift, macos

I am creating an Xcode command line utility app that should read urls from a JSON file and check each URL to see if it returns a 200 HTTP code or not. I have this so far:

```
  Services.shared.readJsonFile { file in

        if file == nil {
            print("File does not exist!")
            print(FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
        }

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            for servers in (file?.monitors)! {

                dispatchGroup.enter()

                let urlString = servers.url

                print("1")

                Services.shared.checkConnection(url: urlString, id: servers.component_id) { conresult in

                     print("2")

                    if conresult == .down {

                        print("\(urlString) is DOWN!")


                    } else {

                        print("\(urlString) is UP!")


                    }

                    dispatchGroup.leave()

                }

            }

            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
            }

    }

    dispatchMain()
```

It should loop through each URL and print whether the url is up or down but instead the output is as follows:

```
1
1
2
https://esg3g2sdg32.com is DOWN!
2
https://esg3g2sdg32.com is DOWN!
logout
```

It ends up printing 1 a few times and then printing 2 a couple times instead of printing 1 once and 2 once.

**UPDATE:**
Added semaphores:

```
Services.shared.readJsonFile { file in

    print(FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)

    if file == nil {
        print("File does not exist!")
        //print(FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
    }

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue")
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()


        for servers in (file?.monitors)! {

        dispatchQueue.async {

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            semaphore.wait()

            let urlString = servers.url

            print("1")

            Services.shared.checkConnection(url: urlString, id: servers.component_id) { conresult in

                print("2")

                if conresult == .down {

                    print("\(urlString) is DOWN!")


                } else {

                    print("\(urlString) is UP!")

                }

                dispatchGroup.leave()
                semaphore.signal()
            }

        }
    }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {

            //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
        }

}

dispatchMain()
```

Ouput is now as follows:

```
1
2
https://google.com is UP!
1
2
https://esg3g2sdg32.com is DOWN!
2
https://esg3g2sdg32.com is DOWN!
Illegal instruction: 4
logout
```

It starts out well by printing 1,2 url, then another 1,2 and second url but then it only prints 2 and the second url again.

Comment: The array may has  2 items

Comment: @Sh_Khan the array only has 2 items in it. It should loop only twice.

Comment: you print 1 for every loop and 2 inside the completion  2*2 = 4 plus 2 https log

Comment: If the array has really two items, the output correspond exactly to the code you gave. I see nothing wrong there. `print("1")` is INSIDE the for loop, so it should be printed twice, that's normal.

Comment: @Larme I want the network request to complete before it starts the second loop. It looks like it's printing 1 twice and then completing the first loop. That what I tried to use the dispatch group for.

Comment: Use semaphores? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741910/swift-block-loop-from-continuing-until-download-operation-finishes) or create a function that has an array of urls in param, it loads only the first item, and in whichever case (success/fail) it removes the first item of the array and call itself?

Comment: @Larme I updated question after adding semaphore. It starts out ok but then it runs the second url twice.

Comment: Could it be an issue with how `checkConnection` handles a down connection?

Comment: @CleverError that was it! thx